# Why is a www to no-www redirect so slow?

Tags: redirects, optimization, load-time

I'm quite new to running a website, and I've recently run my page through some page load time measurements to try and reduce load time. After scaling down my images etc, I find that the bottleneck comes from 'wait' time, notably time spent waiting for a redirect from my www domain to the domain without www.

Is there a way to prevent the additional load time caused by the redirect, while still having my page be accessible with or without the www in the URL?

I am running on a Wordpress installation on DreamHost.

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/cmbT5V/http://www.kiwifoodie.co.nz

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68812/whats-causing-the-wait-time-before-my-html-loads) is about why the wait times are slow when loading page, but it does not address redirects.

Comment: Most users are not going to encounter that slowness.  Once they are one your site, the links don't include the www.   Search engines and other sites would generally link to the version without the www.   Only type in traffic that includes the www would have that problem.  Is it really a problem that needs to be solved?

Comment: How are you hosting it on Dreamhost?  Are you using the "one click installs"?   If you do so, they put your site on a server that only serves WordPress sites and is optimized for it.  I have [a site](http://www.maynardcommunityband.com/) set up that way and the www to no-www redirect takes only 0.195s where your www to no-www redirect takes 1.628s.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Stephen. I am hosting it using the one click install, yep. So you think the redirect is unlikely to be an issue and it just seems like that 'on paper' (ie in the test pages)?

Hope this question isn't too off topic but, does my site seem to load very slowly to you? Or is it about average?

Comment: Its worth testing without the www in the URL because most users are not going to be using your site that way.  Dreamhost is not known for its performance.   If you want a fast website, don't use Dreamhost.  I host some things there because they are cheap and I've had an account for about 10 years now, but my money making sites that need to be fast are hosted elsewhere.

Comment: Which web hosts have decent performance for a reasonable price? I've tried searching for reviews, but it's hard to know which reviews to trust and which not to.

Comment: I pay much more for my other hosting.    I haven't be able to find a host that is comparable to Dreamhost in price that works better than it.

Comment: How are you redirecting? Are you letting WordPress handle this or are you using .htaccess? WordPress/PHP will naturally be a lot slower than .htaccess. (Aside: [this recent problem](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71825/rewriterule-change-email-htme-someonesomewhere-comh-xxxxxx/71827) was caused by WordPress's www/non-www redirection.)

Comment: Interesting note, thanks. I was using DreamHost's redirect option. I should be looking at handling it via code in .htaccess instead, then?

Comment: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/O5NST/http://kiwifoodie.co.nz without the redirect is evidence that the server you are using has a rubbish first byte.

Comment: 3.5 sec seems okay by my standards, I wouldn't have been concerned by that. The 13 second one I posted is really bad though.

Comment: 3.78 sec is not ok with Google standards. Google now rewards for faster sites. Try using .htaccess method rather then using your control panel to do the redirect. But even then your going to be looking at a 4-5 sec which is still very high. If you had decent hosting the byte would be less and that 3.78 would be below 1.50 which Google will love and your users.  You should also note that on mobile devices that 3.78secs becomes easily 5-6 seconds because obviously the download speed is slower.

Comment: What hosting would you recommend to achieve that?

Comment: You should also note that pingdoms servers are on the other side of the planet to New Zealand, if that is indeed where your site is hosted?

Comment: My site has a NZ domain name but is currently hosted by DreamHost, which I assume has servers in the US. I haven't managed to find a decent and reasonably priced host in NZ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to speed up the redirect, instead of using DreamHost for your DNS services and adding a site redirect in DreamHost, you might manage your DNS through your domain name registrar (Aust Domains), whose services if you're lucky may use anycast DNS and perform much faster. You would then setup the HTTP redirect in their control panel.

[image]

Pricing for shared web hosting is always dependent on requirements - for example, the amount of diskspace required, bandwidth required. Since in reality, you get what you pay for, if you are looking for unlimited diskspace and unlimited bandwidth but also a premium level of performance this will not come cheap however if you work out what you actually need in terms of diskspace and bandwidth and then shop around you might find a premium performance hosting solution that fits your requirements without the high price.

Alternatively Pay-As-You-Go cloud hosting solutions such as Amazon S3, Microsoft Azure, Google Cloud etc., can offer high performance for low budget if your diskspace and bandwidth requirements are not excessive.

You could also use a CDN/acceleration service such as CloudFlare to improve your DNS, redirects and site performance.

Comment: Thank you!

What do you think about using Google App Engine within the free quota? I'm not sure how to estimate how much bandwidth and diskspace I will need though. Will have to look that up. I get on average only about 20 (human) views per day.

With the pay-as-you-go model is there a possibility that I will receive a huge charge if traffic surges or there is an attack, or lots of bot access?

Comment: Google App Engine allows you to set a maximum daily budget, some other cloud services allow you to set a monthly cap on spending. Provided you set this you should be safe from unexpectedly high bills following a traffic spike, though at the cost of your services being replaced with an over-quota error message until the next day. Some services allow you to configure rate-limiting which if well configured can be more effective at limiting cost while ensuring a consistent level of service for genuine users before and after a traffic spike.

Comment: For reference, I've just tested the Enom (Domain Name Registrar)'s URL-Redirect configured alongside DNS host records, vs DreamHost's redirect and the results for me are: Enom 331ms, DreamHost 435ms - however this will obviously vary based on physical distances, virtual infrastructure and network traffic at the time etc so it is of cause possible the results could be the other way around if I try later tonight. Typically though since the web servers at my registrar are *only* doing redirects I would expect them to respond quicker.

Answer (score 0):

> Interesting note, thanks. I was using DreamHost's redirect option. I should be looking at handling it via code in .htaccess instead, then?

This is the difference: my site does this redirect quickly on Dreamhost and yours does not.   Dreamhost has a setting for this that makes it work quickly.  It can be set outside of wordpress using the Dreamhost panel:

[image]

To get this:

1. Log into https://panel.dreamhost.com/
2. Click on "Manage domains"
3. Click the "Edit" button next to your fully hosted domain

Comment: Thanks, Stephen! I have put the change in and the DH control panel says it is pending, will test the speed out again once it goes through. Purely out of curiosity... why would removing the www work faster than the other two options?

Comment: In reality, all these redirect solutions will be using the same method of a web-server returning an HTTP 301 Redirect header with a URL, so whether this is done yourself via .htaccess, or done by Dreamhost using a .htaccess rule (this is how they outwork the options you choose in the DreamHost Panel), or done using a lighter web server than Apache doesn't really make much difference, the key is all about how high specification the instrastructure and network speeds are where this happens. I suggested moving the DNS as then you'll see increase in speed on A record lookups too at no extra cost.